# Mac の VSCode でフォーマットのショートカットを実行すると Ï が入力されてしまう

Tags: macos, vscode

MacでVSCodeを使っており、<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> でフォーマット出来ると見たのですが、
`Ï` が入力されフォーマットできません。

Comment: 入力モード(IME)は何を利用されている状態ですか？手元で試したところ(OSが古いのですが)、macOS標準の日本語入力では当該のショートカットがたしかに利用できませんでした。(英字入力やGoogle日本語入力では問題なさそう)

Answer (score 2):

何か拡張入れてないでしょうか？
拡張機能でキー割当を変更している場合もあるかもなので

VS Code左下の「管理」から[キーボード・ショートカット] (もしくは <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>, あるいは <kbd>⌘ K</kbd><kbd>⌘ S</kbd>) で, キー・バインドがわかります

そこに `format` もしくは `doc for` などタイプすると状況が分かるかも
(以下は Ubuntuでの場合)
[image: Ubuntuで実際タイプしたところ]